# Solving recurrence equations with the help of Generating Functions

Tags: combinatorics

I need to solve this recurrence equation with the help of Generating Functions in Combinatorics.

Given:
$$f(0) = 0 , f(1) = 1, f(n) = 10f(n-1) - 25f(n-2) \forall n \geq 2$$

So I said the following:

$$f(n) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {10(n-1)x^n} - \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {25(n-2)x^n}$$

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The generating function is
$$g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k) x^k = f(0) + f(1) x + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} f(k) x^k = x + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(10f(k-1) - 25f(k-2))x^k$$
Hence,
$$g(x) = x + 10 x \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(k) x^k -25x^2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k) x^k = x+10x g(x) - 25x^2 g(x)$$
This gives us
$$g(x) = \dfrac{x}{(5x-1)^2}$$
Now expand the above as a Taylor series about origin and compare coefficients to get $f(k)$.

Comment: A few questions.
Why is $ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} {(10f(k-1) - 25f(k-2)       )x^k} = 10x \sum_{k=1}{\infty} {f(k)x^k} - 25x^2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {f(k) x^k}$ ?

Comment: @TheNotMe Write out few terms and see what you get.

Comment: I don't understand..

Comment: @TheNotMe Write the terms in the series. You need to put pen on paper and write out few terms, you will then see why what I wrote is true.

Comment: Ah, I understand.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use Wilf's techniques from "generatingfunctionology". Write:
$$
f(n + 2) = 10 f(n + 1) - 25 f(n) \qquad f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1
$$
Define:
$$
F(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} f(n) z^n
$$
From the recurrence:
$$
\frac{F(z) - f(0) - f(1) z}{z^2} = 10 \frac{F(z) - f(0)}{z} - 25 F(z)
$$
Thus:
$$
F(z) = \frac{z}{(1 - 5 z)^2} 
     = - \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - 5 z} 
           + \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{(1 - 5 z)^2}
$$
Using the expansion:
$$
(1 - u)^{-r} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{-r}{n} (-1)^n u^n
             = \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n + r - 1}{r - 1} u^n
$$
this gives:
$$
f(n) = \frac{1}{5} \left(- \binom{n}{0} 5^n + \binom{n + 1}{1} 5^n \right)
     = n 5^{n - 1}
$$